# Windows Runtime metadata is invalid in Windows SDK Error in Windows 10 Universal app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Windows Runtime metadata is invalid in Windows SDK Error occurs when i deploy app in release mode to device/emulator, what i have to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more data? I assume you're running a UWP app, are you developing on a preview release of Windows? What SDK version are you targeting? Are you using any special functions (E.g. Camera or Internet)?